# Web part checkboxes does not work as it should

Tags: html, sharepoint, checkbox, web-parts

I am working on a Sharpoint site. I have created a Form Web Part, which is connected to a status column in a List. The web part is used to filter the list. In the web part, I have 7 checkboxes to filter the list. When I select one of the checkbox, the list gets filtered, as expected, but it checks all other 6 checkboxes.  This is really annoying behavior. Can someone help?

Here is the HTML source I used for webpart:

------>

```
<div onkeydown="javascript:if (event.keyCode == 13) _SFSUBMIT_">
<input type="checkbox" name="Status" value="Approved" checked="checked">Approved<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Status" value="Beta-Test" >Beta-Test<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Status" value="Under-Development" >Under-Development<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Status" value="Created" >Created<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Status" value="Rejected" >Rejected<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Status" value="Estimated" >Estimated<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Status" value="Deployed" >Deployed<br>
<input type="button" value="Go" onclick="javascript:_SFSUBMIT_"/>
</div>
```

<------

[image: Sequence of operations]

1. Select one of the status.
2. Click on GO.
3. Filter operations on the list suceeds, but all the checkboxes are selected :(.

Thanks in advance.
Madhu

Comment: 'I have removed "<" in the beginning of first line' - Why?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not good in javascript but i can say that you have  it works if u get one value. But as u want to store multiple value need to have an array. That is name="status[]" . This may work

Comment: Hello Venkat, thanks for the reply. Yes, the filter mechanism works, but the real problem is that it checks all the other checkboxes.  Which is annoying.

Comment: I have added a pic to elaborate my question again.

Comment: Hmmm. Sorry i'm not good in js but if you use php its easy for me to solve the problem. I'm at very basic in js development